# UIView animation not work

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewanimation

I'd like to make `settingView` on `myView` display and disappear with animation.
I call `-showSettingView`
`if (!self.settingView)` : the animation correctly work.
But, `else if (self.myView)` : `settingView` disappear WITHOUT animation.
How do I fix it to make `settingView` disappear with animation?

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIView *myView;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIView *settingView;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UIBarButtonItem* settingButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAction target:self action:@selector(showSettingView)];
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = settingButton;
}

- (void)showSettingView
{
    self.myView = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 568, 320, 480)];
    self.myView.opaque = NO;
    self.myView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:1.0f alpha:0.0f];
    [self.view addSubview:self.myView];

    if (!self.settingView) {
        self.settingView = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 568)];
        self.settingView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        [self.myView addSubview:self.settingView];
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3f
                              delay:0.0f
                            options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromBottom
                         animations:^{self.myView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 60, 320, 480);}
                         completion:^(BOOL finished) {}
         ];
    } else if (self.myView){
        self.myView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 60, 320, 480);
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3f
                              delay:0.0f
                            options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseIn
                         animations:^{self.myView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 568, 320, 480);}
                         completion:^(BOOL finished) {}
         ];
        [self.settingView removeFromSuperview];
        self.settingView = nil;
        [self.myView removeFromSuperview];
    }
}
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You dealloc the settings view before the animation starts. Try this:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.3f
                          delay:0.0f
                        options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseIn
                     animations:^{self.myView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 568, 320, 480);}
                     completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                        [self.settingView removeFromSuperview];
                        self.settingView = nil;
                        [self.myView removeFromSuperview];
                     }
     ];
```

*Also: If you are using auto layout you need to do one of these options:

A. Set the constrains of `myView` instead of the frame, before the block, and then call **only** `layoutIfNeeded:` inside the block.

B. Set the `transform` property in the animation block.

Answer (score 2):

Try adding this line 
`[self layoutIfNeeded];`
as the last line within your animation block. Something like that:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.3f
                      delay:0.0f
                    options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromBottom
                 animations:^{
                     self.myView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 60, 320, 480);
                     // any other stuff you have to move

                     [self layoutIfNeeded];
                 }
                 completion:^(BOOL finished) {}
];
```